# Given a List of Integers, find the most frequently occurring integer in the list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had this come up in an interview recently. Given a list of integers find the most frequently occurring integer in the list and return in an array. I was able to answer, but one of the test cases threw me off.

I'm stuck on what kind of sorting method I should use to sort the the array for the most frequent integer and return all items in the array that contain the most common integer.

```
const arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,10]; // return 3 

const mostCommon = (arr) => {
 if (arr.length < 1 ) {
     return null;
 }
    const map = {};
    let mostFrequentNum = arr[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let currentNum = arr[i];
        !map[currentNum] ? map[currentNum] = 1 : ++map[currentNum];
        // 1. Current has higher count than known max
        if(map[currentNum] > map[mostFrequentNum]) {
        mostFrequentNum = currentNum;
       }
    }
    return mostFrequentNum;
};
mostCommon(arr); // return 3

/* confused how to implement test case below */
// const arr = [5, 99, 3994813, 99, -32, 43, 99, 3994813, 3994813]; 
// return [ 99, 3994813 ]
```

Comment: Surely you don't want to `return` from inside that `if` statement; you'll skip part of the original array.

Comment: The most naive solution: After you sorted the array, on the first iteration find the number of occurrences of the most frequent number(s). Then on the second iteration return all numbers that occur that many times.

Comment: Your question is confusing: you use the word "integer", singular, but then you also say you want an array with more than one value in case there's a tie.  Which is it?

Comment: @Pointy it's not infrequent for useless and silly interview questions to be poorly worded :-)

Comment: @pointy thanks. I didn't mean to return inside the if statement. I corrected it. I think the interviewer meant to ask for the most common integer in the first test case and all sets of nums in the array containing the most frequent integer in the second test case, I was confused with how it was worded as well. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just accumulate the counts like you're doing, and then *after* that's finished go through and find the biggest count.

```js
    const arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,10]; 
    
    const mostCommon = (arr) => {
        const map = {};
        for (currentNum of arr) {
          !map[currentNum] ? map[currentNum] = 1 : ++map[currentNum];
        }
        let result = Object.keys(map).reduce((r, n) => {
          if (map[n] > r.c) {
            r.c = map[n];
            r.n = n;
          }
          return r;
        }, { c: -1 });
        return result.n;
    };
    console.log(mostCommon(arr));

    console.log(mostCommon([5, 99, 3994813, 99, -32, 43, 99, 3994813, 3994813]));
```

The `.reduce()` process keeps an object that includes fields for the number from the original array, and its count.

Your question uses "integer" singular but your examples suggest you'd like the *list* of values that tie for the largest count. To do that, you'd modify the above to maintain the `.reduce()` accumulator with a list instead of just a simple scalar:

```js
    const arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,10]; 
    
    const mostCommon = (arr) => {
        const map = {};
        for (currentNum of arr) {
          !map[currentNum] ? map[currentNum] = 1 : ++map[currentNum];
        }
        let result = Object.entries(map).reduce((r, [n, c]) => {
          if (c > r.max) r.max = c;
          r[c] ? r[c].push(n) : r[c] = [n];
          return r;
        }, { max: -1 });
        return result[result.max];
    };
    console.log(mostCommon(arr));

    console.log(mostCommon([5, 99, 3994813, 99, -32, 43, 99, 3994813, 3994813]));
```

Comment: thank you. this is an excellent implementation that I can truly learn from.

Answer (score 0):

I have only 1 solution ;)

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,10];

var
  counting  = {},
  most_Freq = arr[0]
  ;

arr.forEach( x=>{ counting[x] = (counting[x] || 0)+1; });

most_Freq = Object.keys(counting).reduce((a, b) => counting[a] > counting[b] ? a : b);

console.log ( 'most frequent is ', most_Freq )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()` to create a Map of numbers with frequencies.

Use `Math.max()` get highest frequency from the `Map.values()`.

Convert the Map to an array of entries ([key, value]), filter out the items with frequency lower than the highest frequency, and map to a list of numbers.

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 10];

const mostCommon = arr => {
  const freqMap = arr.reduce((r, n) => r.set(n, (r.get(n) || 0) + 1), new Map); // create a Map of number by frequency
  
  const highestFreq = Math.max(...freqMap.values()); // get the highest frequency number
  
  return Array.from(freqMap) // convert the Map to an array of entries
    .filter(([, v]) => v === highestFreq) // filter lower frequency items
    .map(([k]) => k); // convert back to an array of numbers
}

console.log(mostCommon(arr));

console.log(mostCommon([5, 99, 3994813, 99, -32, 43, 99, 3994813, 3994813]));
```